# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.maps.android'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I added library in my project but I encounter this error :

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.maps.android'
    You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
    However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

How to avoid this error? I tried solution found on internet like :

- add android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
- eclude group {com.google.maps.android}

But no success.

Here is my app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "me.eazypark.eazypark"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':library')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
}
```

Here is my library build.gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
   apply plugin: 'maven'
   apply plugin: 'signing'

   archivesBaseName = 'android-maps-utils'
   group = 'com.google.maps.android'

   dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
   }


   android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

resourcePrefix 'amu_'

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }

    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
    }
}

// This enables long timeouts required on slow environments, e.g. Travis
adbOptions {
    timeOutInMs 10 * 60 * 1000  // 10 minutes
    installOptions "-d","-t"
}

}

 task instrumentTest(dependsOn: connectedCheck)

 task apklib(type: Zip) {
dependsOn 'check'
appendix = extension = 'apklib'

from 'AndroidManifest.xml'
into('res') {
    from 'res'
}
into('src') {
    from 'src'
}
}

artifacts {
archives apklib
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classifier = 'sources'
}

signing {
sign configurations.archives
}

if (!hasProperty("sonatypeUsername")) {
sonatypeUsername = ""
}
if (!hasProperty("sonatypePassword")) {
sonatypePassword = ""
}

uploadArchives {
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2') {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword)
        }
        snapshotRepository(url: 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/') {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword)
        }

        modifyPom(addFilter('aar') { artifact, file ->
            artifact.name == 'android-maps-utils'
        })

        modifyPom(addFilter('apklib') { artifact, file ->
            artifact.name == 'android-maps-utils-apklib'
        })

        // There's no official apklib for Google Play services, so we
        // can't really maintain that dependency for the apklib packaging.
        pom('apklib').whenConfigured { pom ->
            pom.dependencies = []
        }
    }
   }
 }

 def modifyPom(pom) {
pom.project {
    name 'Google Maps Android API utility library'
    description 'Handy extensions to the Google Maps Android API.'
    url 'https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils'

    scm {
        url 'scm:git@github.com:googlemaps/android-maps-utils.git'
        connection 'scm:git@github.com:googlemaps/android-maps-utils.git'
        developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:googlemaps/android-maps-utils.git'
    }

    licenses {
        license {
            name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
            url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
            distribution 'repo'
        }
    }

    organization {
        name 'Google Inc'
        url 'http://developers.google.com/maps'
    }

    developers {
        developer {
            id 'broady'
            name 'Chris Broadfoot'
            url 'http://google.com/+ChristopherBroadfoot'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Tanks!

Comment: Remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`. See if that helps. (also I believe 9.0 is the latest version if you care)

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle`, You dont need to add both `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` and `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-**:8.4.0'`. Either you should define specifically which play-services that you are using , or you just need to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` only..